# Paper.js rotate group around pivot onMouseDrag

Tags: javascript, paperjs

How can I achieve rotating group around pivot in onMouseDrag event. So you can imagine what I mean here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r12vaw95/3/),

```
var point1 = new Point(150, 150);
  var point2 = new Point(250, 150);
  path.add(point1);
  path.add(point2);

  var handle1 = new Path.Circle({
    center    : point1,
    radius    : 7,
    fillColor : 'green'
  });

  var handle2 = new Path.Circle({
    center    : point2,
    radius    : 7,
    fillColor : 'blue'
  });

  var group = new Group(path, handle1, handle2);
  group.pivot = point1;

  handle1.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
    group.position = group.position.subtract(handle1.position).add(event.point);
  };

  handle2.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
    group.rotate(event.point.angle - handle2.position.angle)
  };
```

There is a path with two handles at the edges. Green handle1 works ok, it should move whole path. And blue handle2, when dragged, should rotate path around green point according to mouse position. Code I've got there works ok, but only for cca 180 low degrees.

What am I missing here?

Thank you very much for any kind of help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you declare the pivot point of an object A to be the position of another object B, it does not automatically update if object B changes position. You'll have to change it every time you use `handle1.onMouseDrag`:

```
handle1.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
    group.position = group.position.subtract(handle1.position).add(event.point);
    group.pivot = event.point;
};
```

As for the rotation, you probably want to rotate the group by the difference between `event.point` and the group's current angle. In your current code, you are rotating by the angle of (0,0) to `event.point` minus the angle of (0,0) to `handle1`. Try this instead:

```
group.rotate(event.point.subtract(handle1.position).angle - (handle2.position.subtract(handle1.position)).angle);
```

[Here's an updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/r12vaw95/4/)